# 'Error using pandas-datareader: No data fetched using 'YahooDailyReader'

Tags: pandas-datareader

I've seen a similar question asked, but not answered. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
symbols = ['MSFT','AMZN','AAPL','GOOG','FB']
start_date = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2019,7,1)
stock_data = web.get_data_yahoo(symbols,start_date,end_date)
print(stock_data.head())
```

I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b17e3a4d0dcf> in <module>
      2 start_date = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)
      3 end_date = datetime.datetime(2019,7,1)
----> 4 stock_data = web.get_data_yahoo(symbols,start_date,end_date)
      5 print(stock_data.head())

~/anaconda3/envs/stocks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs)
     84 
     85 def get_data_yahoo(*args, **kwargs):
---> 86     return YahooDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
     87 
     88 

~/anaconda3/envs/stocks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in read(self)
    256             df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols.index)
    257         else:
--> 258             df = self._dl_mult_symbols(self.symbols)
    259         return df
    260 

~/anaconda3/envs/stocks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _dl_mult_symbols(self, symbols)
    275         if len(passed) == 0:
    276             msg = "No data fetched using {0!r}"
--> 277             raise RemoteDataError(msg.format(self.__class__.__name__))
    278         try:
    279             if len(stocks) > 0 and len(failed) > 0 and len(passed) > 0:

RemoteDataError: No data fetched using 'YahooDailyReader'
```

Hoping someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in a github page:https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/868

The solution was:

```
import pandas
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yfin
yfin.pdr_override()

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("TSLA", start="yyyy-mm-dd", end="yyyy-mm-dd")
print(df)
```